# Problem linking libjpeg on Android

Tags: android, libjpeg

I'm having a problem linking to libjpeg from the Android source. I have

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libjpeg
```

and

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../froyo/external/jpeg
```

but I still get undefined references to anything from that library. I've tried changing "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES" to "LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES" but that did nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use #include in this form:

```
extern "C" {
#include "jpeglib.h"
}
```

It worked for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

libjpeg is not built as a shared library on Android Froyo. You need to link to it as a static library, e.g.:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libjpeg
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := external/jpeg
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. And there is a libjpeg.so in the android source.

Comment: I'm using it here in a custom Android Froyo build, so I can only guess the source of your problem lies elsewhere...